# How many times can you toss a coin at most for the probability of never having heads to be at least 15%

Tags: probability

I do not understand this question at all. Can someone give me a hint on how to start? 
From What I understood I get
$$
1/2 \cdot 1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 0.125
$$
or
$$
(1/2)^n = 0.15
$$
$$n= \log_i 0.15
$$
Where i= 0.5
Then I plug in to find n which equals to 2.737 But i'm not sure if either of these are correct.

Comment: So, if you toss it fewer than 2.737 times, the probability of never having heads will be more than 15%.  You can toss it 0,1,or 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of heads we observe. We wish for

$$P(X=0)={n \choose 0}0.5^n=0.5^n\geq 0.15$$

Here you should find $n\leq 2.74$

where the sign flips because $0.5<1$.

The greatest value $n$ can take on is $2$ since we cannot flip a coin $2.74$ times. Well, at least I can't.